# Deep Querying in Firebase Realtimedatabase

Tags: javascript, firebase-realtime-database

Consider the following Json Structure in the Firebase realtime database

```
"reports": {
  "-LsqM6BMBcbpSurPUQI7": {
    "reportedTo": {
      "L1": {
        "-LwDyYzua6MN1biKVSSk": {
          "timestamp": 1576504280133,
          "user": "TdmqmdWUKATcCYsjWH12SZek87j1"
        },
        "-LwDyZ3a2bCvWKqK2FAP": {
          "timestamp": 1576504280633,
          "user": "s4GJ42t1zdbur48OQwzMgrn2p4B2"
        }
      },
      "L2": {
        "-LwE4QRrvmhhkkMKnu1f": {
          "timestamp": 1576506079146,
          "user": "DdZgodGjFOg2fNPJPKPT9wcqa2G3"
        },
        "-LwE4QY4ctY7SV_q-gIC": {
          "timestamp": 1576506079445,
          "user": "uBzlslel6lPVmf1JWWLW7XjoAd63"
        }
      },
      "L3": {
        "-LwEBHeDTDE9jW89xEQs": {
          "timestamp": 1576507878046,
          "user": "vilGHQlpSPUQ77hnLr5OzmsrGTz1"
        },
        "-LwEBHeDTDE9jW89xEQt": {
          "timestamp": 1576507878046,
          "user": "vilGHQlpSPUQ77hnLr5OzmsrGTz1"
        }
      }
    },
  },
  "-LsqM94G-y5T6WAIfvJh": {
    ...something similar to above
  }
}
```

Basically, this is a db of reports. I want to get the list of those reports, which are reported to a particular user, say "DdZgodGjFOg2fNPJPKPT9wcqa2G3".

As per my understanding of the documentation, it appears to be difficult. Is it possible to jump 2 levels of unique ids? As in this case.

Comment: Maybe you can use filtering methods like where clause etc.. check this https://cloud.google.com/firestore/docs/query-data/queries

Comment: Realtime Database?